# JavaFx WebView Not Refresh

Tags: java, webview, javafx-2, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using ScheduledExecutorService of Java with JavaFx WebView.
I want to refresh WebView after some time interval.

```
 private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);

 @FXML
 private WebView webView;
 int i = 0;

 @Override
 public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
     Runnable runPeriodic = new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             System.out.println("REFRESH");

             if((i % 2) == 0) {
                 System.out.println("i=" + i);
                 webView.getEngine().load("http://www.google.co.in");
             } else {
                 System.out.println("i=" + i);
                 webView.getEngine().load("http://www.bing.com");
             } 

             i++;
         }
    };

    ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runPeriodic, 10, 30, SECONDS);
}
```

My internet connection is working fine but why this webView is not refreshing?

Comment: You should access the web ending through the JavaFX Thread.

Comment: `Runnable runPeriodic = new Runnable() { public void run() { Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { /*your code here */ }}) }});`